# sending php array to javascript function onclick

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Little problem about sending PHP array to javascript function, i did homework looked everywhere and i know its not reliable to do this, but at this moment i do not know any other way , so try to just advice me how to finish it anyway.

I got php code executing first , idea is on page load i get some data from MySQL , i filled php array with IDs from that select statement.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$TicketExist = "select BetSlipID,probatip1.betslips.MatchID as GameID, 
TipID,tim1.Name AS HomeTeam ,tim2.Name AS AwayTeam, UserID 
from probatip1.betslips
inner join probatip1.matches matches on probatip1.betslips.MatchID = matches.MatchID
inner join probatip1.teams tim1 on matches.HomeTeamID = tim1.TeamID
inner join probatip1.teams tim2 on matches.AwayTeamID = tim2.TeamID
where UserID = 1";

$TicketResult = mysql_query($TicketExist);
$TicketNum = mysql_numrows($TicketResult);

mysql_close();

if($TicketNum != 0)
{
$s=0;
while($s < $TicketNum)
{       

    $GameID = mysql_result($TicketResult,$s,"GameID");
    $TipID = mysql_result($TicketResult,$s,"TipID");    
    $ArrayIDs[$s] = $GameID;
    echo "<script>window.onload=GetInfo($GameID,$TipID); </script>";
    $s++;
}
} 
?>
```

So i got it everything i want filled and wrote on my page , idea now is on user click , to call javascript to take this '$ArrayIDs' and execute code from script

Here is code im calling script

```
<ul>
<li 
id="ConfirmButton" name="Insert" method="post" 
onclick="GetAllIDs(<?php $ArrayIDs ?>)"><a>POTVRDI</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my script code

```
function GetAllIDs(Ticket) {
$("td.ID").each(function () {

    var MatchID = $(this).attr('id');
    var lab = "Label";

    var Label = lab + MatchID;

    var Final = document.getElementById(Label);

    var TipID;

    if (Final.innerHTML == '1') {
        TipID = 1;
    }
    else if (Final.innerHTML == 'X') {
        TipID = 2;
    }
    else if (Final.innerHTML == '2') {
        TipID = 3;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }


    var request_type;
    var browser = navigator.appName;


    if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    var http = request_type;

    var AlreadyPlayed = false;

    if (Ticket != null) {
        var TicketExists = Ticket;
        for (var i = 0; i < TicketExists.length; i++) {
            if (TicketExists[i] == MatchID) {
                AlreadyPlayed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (http != null) {

        if (AlreadyPlayed == true) {
            http.open('get', 'update.php?MatchID=' + MatchID + 
            '&TipID=' + TipID + '&UserID=' + 1, true);
        }
        else {
            http.open('get', 'insert.php?MatchID=' + MatchID + 
            '&TipID=' + TipID + '&UserID=' + 1, true);
        }
        http.send(null);
    }
});

if (Ticket == null) {
    alert('Tiket je napravljen');
}
else {
    alert('Tiket je promenjen');
}
}
```

With this posted code when i am debugging code with firebug in mozzila i get that my 'Ticket' parameter that suppose to be '$ArrayIDs' is undefined.

Reason why i want to make array and send it to javascript onclick event is to check if user already placed a bet on some game , if he did i want to send all data for update and if he did not yet placed bet on some game to send data for insert in database.
So i need array and before anything just to check MatchID with all IDs in my array, so i know what to do.

Thanks all in advance for helping out

Comment: you need to use json to pass array from php to javascript

Comment: And Yes use mysqli_ or pdo instead of mysql_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script could do with a bit of cleanup, but in essence you need to change

```
onclick="GetAllIDs(<?php $ArrayIDs ?>)">
```

to

```
onclick="GetAllIDs(<?php echo json_encode($ArrayIDs) ?>)">
```

I'd also reccomend not outputting

```
"<script>window.onload=GetInfo($GameID,$TipID); </script>";
```

for each row in mysql, instead create a single array of the values and create one script after the loop. Using mysql_fetch_row instead of mysql_numrows and mysql_result is probably neater.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    //...do things here...
}
```

Comment: Finally managed .... 
`onclick="GetAllIDs(<?php echo json_encode($ArrayIDs) ?>)">`
was the key .... i will google a bit more about json_encode , thank you for helping me out so fast

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the array as valid JavaScript, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
GetAllIDs(<?php echo  json_encode($ArrayIDs); ?>)
```